# Pigscript Logic Implementation

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to pigscript. I am stuck while working on the example below.  Could anyone help me on how to get the Output specified below using pigscript?

Input:

```
1|ABC|NC  
1|DEF|NC  
2|CFD|NY  
2|CGF|NY
```

Output:

```
1|ABC,DEF|NC  
2|CFD,CGF|NY
```

Script:

```
A = LOAD 'testfile.txt' USING PigStorage('|') AS (Id:chararray,name:chararray,state:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE Id,name;
C = FOREACH A GENERATE Id,name,state;
C = DISTINCT C;
GROUPED = GROUP B BY Id;
D = FOREACH GROUPED GENERATE group AS Id,c.name AS name_val;
E = JOIN D BY Id, C BY Id;
X = FOREACH E GENERATE D.Id as docid,D.name_val as termid,C.state;
Dump X;
```

Comment: Where is your pigscript implementing 'different scenarios'?

Answer (score 0):

Load the data and group by 1st and 3rd column and then generate the columns,order to get the desired output.

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage('|') AS (f1:int,f2:chararray;f3:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY f1,f3;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (f1,f3),A.f2 AS f2;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE f1,f2,f3;
DUMP D;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Its working as now expected after adding BagToString method.

A = LOAD 'testfile.txt' USING PigStorage('|') AS (f1:int,f2:chararray,f3:chararray);          
B = GROUP A BY (f1,f3);        
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (f1,f3),A.f2 AS f2;  
D = FOREACH C GENERATE f1,  BagToString(f2, ','), f3;  
STORE D INTO '[path]' USING PigStorage('|');
```